# How to Differentiate the Sent and Received MMS in Android

Tags: android, sms, mms

I have developed an Application dealing with the SMS and MMS. I have done my work but the only point of Concern I have is I am not able to Differentiate between the Sent and Received MMSs.

I have got the Code to Differentiate the Sent and Received SMSs, but nothing for MMSs.

Below is the Code for Differentiating the SMS :

```
if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("type")) == 2)
{
 // Managing the Layout 
}
else 
{       
 // Managing the Layout 
}
```

In the Above Code, "("type")) == 2" is doing its bet for the SMS, hopefully there must be something like this for the MMS also.

Can anyone Please help me out here ?

Thanks,
David Brown

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the implementation of the [MmsProvider](https://gitorious.org/0xdroid/packages_providers_telephonyprovider/source/7236c3ad7ff01dd5ece14a2cabbf5ce3a570d793%3asrc/com/android/providers/telephony/MmsProvider.java#L64), you see you can query different types, like `MMS_INBOX` and `MMS_SENT`. That might work.